# Appending float val to list in python

Tags: python-2.7

In The below code 
i get output 
[10.2, 10.399999999999999, 10.6, 10.799999999999999, 11.0, 11.2, 11.399999999999999, 11.6, 11.799999999999999, 12.0]

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import math
start = None
mL=[]
def update_mL_mV_data(mL_factor,i,diff):

        mL_val=((mL_factor + i*diff))
        print mL_val
        mV_val=1000 + i
        mL.append(mL_val)
        print mL

    for i in range(0,10):
        update_mL_mV_data(10.2,i,0.2)
```

Hw can i correct this .

Comment: Please provide a complete question (with a description of the problem and the result you expect vs you have obtained). See [ask].

Comment: Im trying to get list output [10.2, 10.4, 10.6, 10.8, 11.0, 11.2, 11.4, 11.6, 11.8, 12.0] whereas im getting  [10.2, 10.399999999999999, 10.6, 10.799999999999999, 11.0, 11.2, 11.399999999999999, 11.6, 11.799999999999999, 12.0] , so cannot user round function

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding a comment, this will improve the question, and others will upvote it. In addition you need to understand [how floats are stored in memory](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about float arithmetic here:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Solution: Use round function.
For example, if you want to round the value to two decimal places:
-->  mL_val=round(mL_factor + i*diff, 2)